# Mercurial - clone all remote branches at once

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Wondering if `Mercurial` while cloning the repo includes all remote branches as well? Basically I have some proprietary / not used mercurial repository with many branches. I want to clone all of them at once and make backup out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you clone a mercurial repo without any additional arguments, you make a copy of a repository this includes all branches.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/clone :

> hg clone [OPTION]... SOURCE [DEST]
>
> make a copy of an existing repository
>
> Create a copy of an existing repository in a new directory.